# What happened to identify-this-episode tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, identify

What happened to [identify-this-episode](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-episode) tag. I think it's present but now I can't find it. Is it deleted for some purpose? I mean I am going to use it for my new question but it looked removed. Previously thinking to recreate it but thought to know the reason for it's removal. So is it removed for some reason?

Comment: I think to remember that it was once even removed on purpose from a question. Yet I don't know why, looks like a reasonable tag to me.

Comment: We don't need anymore Identify tags...

Comment: @TylerShads True, and I'd be one of the first to support this. Yet ID *is* on-topic for now and I think the case that you know the show but just not the episode is a reasonable situation, for which `identify-this-tv-show` wouldn't really fit. And it's a hundred times better than `identify-this-music-video`, `identify-this-comercial` or `identify-this-tv-trope`, anyway. I might even say this could be the *only* valid ID-type once ID was dropped (*if it would be* dropped at any point in time).

Comment: @TylerShads but the id question i want to ask need this tag and its a valid tag and even exists before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask the question and create the tag.  If it's unanimously hated then we'll get rid of it, if not, then voila!

Comment: Done.... http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13801/identify-this-marvel-animated-crossover-animated-seriess-episode-where-all-marv

Comment: Does my vote count as "universally hated"? :P

Comment: @TylerShads nope